# solr streams shortestpath errors on id with colon

Tags: solr, stream, escaping, shortest-path

I have the following simple expression `expr=shortestPath(core_data,from="https\://mycompany.com/id/ARMP/AM/GT/ST/CCS1/01/03/05/96/96",to="https\://mycompany.com/id/ARMP/AM/GT/ST/CCS1/01/03/IS/02",edge="id=link_ss",maxDepth="4")`

And this gives an error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: --> http://172.22.0.28:8983/solr/core_data_shard2_replica_n2/:org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'id:([https://mycompany.com/id/STL/KG1/pk_67_4])': Encountered " "]" "] "" at line 1, column 49.
Was expecting:
    "TO" ...
    
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.graph.ShortestPathStream.open(ShortestPathStream.java:366)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.ExceptionStream.open(ExceptionStream.java:52)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.StreamHandler$TimerStream.open(StreamHandler.java:465)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.TupleStream.writeMap(TupleStream.java:79)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JsonTextWriter.writeMap(JsonTextWriter.java:164)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.TextWriter.writeMap(TextWriter.java:216)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.TextWriter.writeVal(TextWriter.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter.writeVal(TextResponseWriter.java:153)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JsonTextWriter.writeNamedListAsMapWithDups(JsonTextWriter.java:387)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JsonTextWriter.writeNamedList(JsonTextWriter.java:293)
    at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeResponse(JSONWriter.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.response.JSONResponseWriter.write(JSONResponseWriter.java:66)
    at org.apache.solr.response.QueryResponseWriterUtil.writeQueryResponse(QueryResponseWriterUtil.java:65)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.writeResponse(HttpSolrCall.java:891)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:584)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:415)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:345)
```

Let me explain further: the link fields I use are `id` (single valued) and `link_ss` (multivalued). Depending on the order I use (`id=link_ss` or `link_ss=id`) I get a different mistake.  `Cannot parse 'link_ss:(https://mycomany.com/id/STL/KG1/pk_67_8/TS_67_8_5152_4 https://mycomany.com/id/STL/KG1/pk_67_4/TS_67_4_260_3 https://mycomany.com/id/STL/KG1/pk_67_4/TS_67_4_260_9)` or the one above. But notice how the parsing error already contains different ids from the original one. So the error really happens internally when crawling through the graph. The query from above indeed does not work, but putting double quotes around the id helps i.e. `link_ss:("https://mycomany.com/id/STL/KG1/pk_67_8/TS_67_8_5152_4")` does work

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did some experiments and it seems that you have to escape the colon (:) in the "from" field, but not in the "to" field of the streaming expressions.
Simply add a backslash before the colon(:) in the "from" field
For instance:

```
shortestPath(oana,from="http\://google.com",to="http://oana1.com",edge="link_from=link_to",maxDepth="1")
```

Comment: Thanks for pinting this oit. However this does not solve my case entirely. Actually it turns out that the error happens internally. I adapted my question